# Put a link on the nav bar in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, links, navigation

I have a Wordpress blog. On the same domain, I have some other stuff hosted that isn't part of my WP install.

I want to link to those other places on my domain from the top menu bar (nav bar) on my blog. How can I do that?

The theme is Lightword, relevant header.php code follows:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper">
<?php lightword_header_image(); ?>
<div id="header">
<?php lightword_rss_feed(); ?>

<div id="top_bar">
<div class="center_menu">
<ul id="front_menu" <?php global $lw_remove_searchbox, $lw_use_wp_menus; $lw_menu_width = ""; if($lw_remove_searchbox == "true") $lw_menu_width = " class=\"expand\" "; echo $lw_menu_width; ?>>
<?php echo lightword_homebtn(__('Home','lightword')); ?>
<?php
if ( function_exists('wp_nav_menu') && $lw_use_wp_menus != "true") {
$lightword_menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'lightword_top_menu', 'echo' => false, 'menu_id' => 'front_menu', 'container' => '', 'theme_location' => 'lightword_top_menu', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) );
$lightword_menu = preg_replace( array( '/^<ul id="front_menu" class="menu">/', '/\n<\/ul>$/' ), '', $lightword_menu);
echo $lightword_menu;
}else{
echo lightword_wp_list_pages();
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php echo lightword_searchbox(); ?>
</div>

</div>
<div id="content">
```

Comment: could you post the code in your header.php file for the theme you are using?

Comment: @Keith done. Nav bar stuff should be somewhere around `$lightword_menu` at line 12

Comment: Ok, you will have to experiment with where exactly to place the code. It's difficult for me to see where to put it without knowing if the php is generating a list item or not. Try this after : echo $lightword_menu; echo '<li><a href="link.html">My Link</a></li>';   Like I said. It may be difficult to know exactly where to place it. But that will give you a start. You can also look at the source code and find the nav links and see if they have classes or id's, then you'd know what to ad there too.

Comment: @Keith, no need, I figured it out without having to mess with any PHP. Right around the time I was trying to concatenate my last menu entry with half of `$lightword_menu`, I realized there was an option buried in the settings pages.

Comment: Excellent! Glad could figure it out!

Comment: Should go to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ honestly.

Comment: I didn't bother migrating this anywhere since it has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings on the backend of Wordpress. :)